Is the Wigner-Ville representation of a non-negative operator a non-negative time-frequency density?
Consider a non-negative operator $K \geq 0$ acting on signals $x$ (say a complex Hilbert space).
The associated quadratic form can take the following temporal representation:
$$\langle x , K x\rangle = \iint x(t)x^\ast(t')K_1(t,t')\text{d} t\text{d} t'$$
or equivalently the following time-frequency representation:
$$ \langle x , Kx\rangle = \iint W_{xx}(t,f)K_2(t,f)\text{d} t\text{d} f$$
written as Wigner-Ville representations:
$$W_{xx}(t,f)=\iint x(t+\tfrac{\tau}{2})x^\ast(t-\tfrac{\tau}{2})e^{-i2\pi f \tau}\text{d} t\text{d} f$$
$$K_2(t,f)=\iint K_1(t+\tfrac{\tau}{2},t-\tfrac{\tau}{2})e^{-i2\pi f \tau}\text{d} t\text{d} f \quad .$$
Is it true that $K_2(t,f)\geq 0$?
